# JQuery script doesn't work twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, numbers

I am trying to create a quiz within a website page. The aim is that every time you press next, a new question will open up within the page. However, calling upon the script a second time doesn't work.

To achieve this, I first created a link called 'next'.

```
<a href="addquiz.html" name="next" id="1">Next</a>
```

This calls upon a script which opens q1 from addquiz.html

```
<script>
$("#1").click(function() {
$("#load").load("addquiz.html" + ' #q1');
event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

In this script there is a submit button which calls upon the function goupone, which increases the id of the link by 1 (eg; from 1 to 2)

```
<div id="q1">
<h3>5 + 19 = ?</h3>
    <input type="text" width="6" name="" id="question-1-answers" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Check" onClick="goupone();" />
</div>

<script>
function goupone(){
var v=document.links[9].id;
vi=parseInt(v);
vi=vi+1;
document.links[9].id=vi;
}
</script>
```

However, when I click the next button again, nothing happens. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just wondering: why do you write `load("addquiz.html" + ' #q1');`? Isn't that the same as `load("addquiz.html #q1");`? What's the point of using concatenation when both parameters are literal strings? Also, is that space before the hash allowed in the URL? My guess is that most browsers will ignore it, but it's not something I would depend on, and there seems to be no need to.

Answer (score 1):

Since you change the `id` from `1` to `2`, the initial click handler `$("#1").click()` will **no longer be triggered** when you click on the anchor. An alternative is to either bind the event handler to an `a` whose attribute `name` is `next`:

```
<script>
$('a[name="next"]').click(function() {
  $("#load").load("addquiz.html" + ' #q1');
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Or create a class, say `next`, add it to `a`, and use it as selector:

```
<a href="addquiz.html" name="next" id="1" class="next">Next</a>

<script>
$('a.next').click(function() {
  $("#load").load("addquiz.html" + ' #q1');
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

However, I'd refactor your entire code to simply use the following instead:

```
<a href="addquiz.html" name="next" id="nextAnchor" data-next-id="1">Next</a>

<script>
$("#nextAnchor").on('click', function() {
  $("#load").load("addquiz.html#q" + $(this).data("next-id"));
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>

function goupone() {
  var $next = $("#nextAnchor");
  var currentId = parseInt($next.data("next-id"));
  var nextId = currentId + 1;
  $next.data("next-id", nextId);
}
```

Here's a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pxkSh/)**.

Comment: I think that a class would be more appropriate than a name here.

Comment: I repeat the script 10 times with I'd going from #1 to #10 and q1 going to q10

Comment: Don't forget that id="1" is not valid. IDs have to start with a letter.

Comment: Would the class account for having multiple questions? (I.e. the same link loading q2 and q3 after q1 and q2 have each been loaded respectively)

Comment: Yes, that's the point of using classes. You can bind something to the entire class, and all instances of it automatically pick this up.

Comment: @user1325305: I've put up a demo to illustrate my last approach: http://jsfiddle.net/pxkSh/. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The function #nextanchor loads the page addquiz.html, without the event.preventDefault() working to keep it on the same page. Any ideas? (I've copied your code over from Fiddle). 

Usually the href of the link has to be exactly the same as in the script for it to load. How can I achieve that?